# Image crop and resizing with CodeIgniter

Tags: image, codeigniter

I'm trying to resize and then upload an image in CodeIgniter. It uploads the image but it doesn't resize it.

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';  
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;  
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;  
$config['quality'] = '60%';  
$config['width'] = 200;  
$config['height'] = 200;  
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);  
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->image_lib->resize()

if ($this->upload->do_upload('resim')) {
    $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();
    $image = $data_upload_files['file_name'];
} else {
    //echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
}
```

Comment: does it give you any error while resizing in the logs?

Comment: no. there are no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are attempting to resize *before* the file is actually uploaded. Secondly, you need to give the image manipulation class the full path to the uploaded image (again, after you uploaded the image). Thirdly, it a good idea to use different variable names for the different configs:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ($this->upload->do_upload('resim')) {
    $file_data = $this->upload->data();
    $resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $resize['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $resize['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $resize['quality'] = '60%';
    $resize['width'] = 200;
    $resize['height'] = 200;
    $resize['source_image'] = $file_data['full_path'];
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $resize);
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
} else {
    echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
}
```